# Change Format of Date Column

Tags: r, posixct, lubridate

I need to turn one date format into another with RStudio, since for `lubridate` and other date related functions a standard unambiguous format is needed for further work. I've included a few examples and informations below:

Example-Dataset:

```
Function,HiredDate,FiredDate
Waitress,16-06-01 12:40:02,16-06-13 11:43:12
Chef,16-04-17 15:00:59,16-04-18 15:00:59
```

Current Date Format (POSIXlt) of `HiredDate` and `FiredDate`:

```
"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

What I want the Date Format of `HireDate` and `FiredDate` to be:

```
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" / 2016-06-01 12:40:02
```

or

```
"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" / 2016/06/01 12:40:02
```

Comment: POSIXlt does not have a specific date format. When you print a POSIXlt vector, then a specific format is used to convert the time stamp into a character, which is then printed. You can control the format of the character with `format()`.

Comment: I have tried converting the following: 

1. use ymd() from the lubricate package to convert my date to appropriate format |||||||||||||||||

2. convert my column into a date.class but losing my time. |||||||||||||||||

3. trying to use POSIXct to somehow get my date |||||||||||||||||

So basically, i haven't tried using something like strftime, it's very difficult to find any other examples.
*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you can convert date and time for example using the strftime function:

```
    d <- "2016-06-01 12:40:02"
    strftime(d, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    [1] "2016/06/01 12:40:02"
```

In your case, the year is causing trouble:

```
    d <- "16-06-01 12:40:02"
    strftime(d, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    [1] "0016/06/01 12:40:02"
```

As Dave2e suggested, the two digit year can be read by %y:

```
    strftime(d, format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    [1] "16/06/01 12:40:02"
```

Assuming that your data comes from the 20st and 21st century, you can paste a 19 or 20 in front of the HireDate and FireDate:

```
    current <- 16
    prefixHire <- ifelse(substr(data$HireDate, 1, 2)<=currentYear,20,19)
    prefixFire <- ifelse(substr(data$FireDate, 1, 2)<=currentYear,20,19)
    data$HireDate = paste(prefixHire, data$HireDate, sep="")
    data$FireDate = paste(prefixFire, data$FireDate, sep="")
```

The code generates a prefix by assuming that any date from a year greater than the current ('16) is actually from the 20th century. The prefix is then pasted to HireDate and FireDate.

Comment: That worked very well, that ifelse construct with substring is something i have to keep in mind for future manipulations, that seems very handy. Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: Use a %y for reading 2 digit years and %Y for 4 digit years. When to use %y - Years without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19